# How do I retrieve an array from a csv file in javascript using d3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, d3.js

Having spent hours on Google and SO, I have finally cracked.

I have a PSQL table of outbound flight data of one day sorted by time and destination continent.
I am going through all rows of my table, pushing the destination continent of each flight into arrays, with each array representing 15mins of flight data. for example,
1st array - `00:00 to 00:15` would be: `[]` ......(no flights)
21st array - `05:00 to 05:15` would be: `["NA", "NA", "NA", "EU", "AS", "EU"]` etc.

all the way to 96 arrays (96 x 15 mins in 24 hours.)

I have this data pushed into a CSV file with the header being just flights
however, when I try to recall the data in d3 using:

`d3.csv("/my_file.csv", function(data) {`
`console.log(data);`
`})`

the object returned is 96 rows of "["NA"" or something equivalent; very obviously it is breaking at the very first comma.  Is there a way to retrieve arrays from a CSV file using d3??

Comment: A similar question came up on google groups [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/YkPWlgnAZQQ) which might help (if you haven't already seen it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files work best when there is a fixed number of columns in each row.  For your data, can you use a [JSON file](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) instead?  There are different ways you could represent your data as JSON, for example, you could use an object with each property being an array:

```
{
    "00:00 to 00:15": [],
    "05:00 to 05:15": ["NA", "NA", "NA", "EU", "AS", "EU"]
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I exported to JSON format and it worked like a charm.